# JavaPNS - works fine from laptop, not from server?

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I've been pounding my head on this for a while, I hope someone can help?
I have some JavaPNS code which pushes fine to my device when running from my local machine, however, when I copy that code over to my server, everything runs fine, no errors, but I never get the alert on my device?
After examining the logs from my server compared to my local box, I noticed I never get the flushing message on my server, I am using the JavaPNS queue, with 30 threads.  In both cases, local box and server, I am sending less than 30 alerts.

```
public class PushWorker 
{
private PushQueue queue = null;

public PushWorker(File keystore, String password, boolean production) throws KeystoreException
{
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    int threads = 30;
    this.queue = Push.queue(keystore, password, production, threads);
    queue.start();
}

public void push(String message, String sound, String token, String eventId) throws JSONException
{
    BasicDevice bd = new BasicDevice();
    bd.setToken(token);

    PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();
    payload.addAlert(message);
    payload.addSound(sound);
    payload.addCustomDictionary("eid", eventId);

    push(payload, bd);
}

private void push(Payload payload, Device device)
{
    queue.add(payload, device);
}
}
```

----BELOW is flush message from my local box --------------

```
4872 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Flushing
4872 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - At this point, the entire 139-bytes message has been streamed out successfully through the SSL connection
4872 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Notification sent on first attempt
```

Can I force the flush somehow from the queue?

----------------------BELOW is the server JavaPNS logging-----------------------

```
0 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocketFactory
16 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocketFactory
49 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocket to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
49 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocket to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
177 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Initialized Connection to Host: [gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com] Port: [2195]: 5117f31e[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com/17.172.233.65,port=2195,localport=56015]]
...
...

DEBUG javapns.notification.Payload  - Adding alert [blah, blah my alert]
14767 [main] DEBUG javapns.notification.Payload  - Adding sound [default]
14767 [main] DEBUG javapns.notification.Payload  - Adding custom Dictionary [eid] = [193790]
14776 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Building Raw message from deviceToken and payload
14776 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Built raw message ID 16777217 of total length 135
14777 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Attempting to send notification: {"aps":{"sound":"default","alert":"blah, blah my alert"},"eid":"193790"}
14777 [JavaPNS grouped notification thread in QUEUE mode] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  -   to device: [my device number]
```

And that's it, no flush...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have iptables configured on the server or some other firewall device?

- Maybe port 2195 needs to be allowed.

Try using telnet to test:

$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195

Do you have SELinux enabled? check the following setting:

$ getsebool -a | grep httpd

httpd_can_network_connect --> ?

make sure it is on.

Did you check the documentation on the javapns repo site?

Let us know how it goes.

Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I don't believe that's the issue, because I can send alerts using this method from the server: Push.payloads(keystore, password, production, list);
I decided to switch to this method of sending in bulk rather than the queue...